# Starred chapter number and name in header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, book-design

I have created custom chapter headings:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Custom macros 
\def \mychapter#1{%
\chapter*{\centering{\LARGE #1}\thispagestyle{empty}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
}

\def \mychapterwithsubtitle#1#2{%
\chapter*{\baselineskip=20pt\centering{\LARGE #1}\\*\vspace*{0.3cm}\textnormal{\Large #2}\thispagestyle{empty}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1: #2}%
}

% Headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Document
\begin{document}
\mychapter{Some chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapterwithsubtitle{Chapter Two}{Subtitle of this chapter}
\lipsum[11-30]
\mychapterwithsubtitle{Chapter Three}{Some other subtitle}
\lipsum[31-50]
\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to be able to put text of `mychapter` heading and name along with subtitles of `mychapterwithsubtitles` headings in the header (let's say left side of odd pages header).

I know that there are commands that could be used with `fancyhdr` package like `\leftmark`, `\rightmark` and `\thechapter`, but those only work for regular chapters and do not produce any result for starred versions of chapters which I tend to use.

Is there any way to put starred chapter name and number in header?

Comment: try adding marks as part of the definition: `\markboth{#1}{#2}` for `\mychapterwithsubtitle`.  (this will position the marks as specified for the `book` class; if you want them somewhere else, then more work is required.)  i don't know what you mean when you refer to "numbers"; by definition, starred chapters aren't numbered.  ???

Comment: @barbarabeeton You are right regarding starred chapters; By 'numbers' I meant first part of chapter heading (#1). I have edited question to reflect that. Your solution indeed works the way you described it, though I hope someone comes up with solution which gives more control over position of those elements.

Comment: Can't promise anything, but i'll have a look into this. I might use another package(s) tough. Not sure.

Comment: @Johannes_B If you find any way to do that, I wil be beyond grateful. Thanks for trying. Situation described in question seems to be something that a lot of people might need, but there is no obvious way to do it that I am aware of.

Comment: As i was reading the question again, i was a bit confused. The only thing to add is, as @barbarabeeton already mentioned, something like `\markright{#1}`. I made a DIY-chapter anyways. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

As Barbara mentioned in her comments, you can use mechnaisms like
`\markboth` or `\markright`.
I just added the mark to your definitions.

I also defined a command `xchapter` that takes an optional
argument that will be typeset as the subtitle. The command in
general patches the original `\@makeschapterhead`, makes the
starting page `empty` and most important, clears the headers of
any pre-existing material.

Since this patches the original book-chapter-definition, it is
not compatible with KOMA-script.

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\def\mychapter#1{%
\chapter*{\centering{\LARGE #1}\thispagestyle{empty}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
\markright{#1}%
}

\def \mychapterwithsubtitle#1#2{%
\chapter*{\baselineskip=20pt\centering{\LARGE#1}\\*\vspace*{0.3cm}\textnormal{\Large#2}\thispagestyle{empty}}%
\markright{#1: #2}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1: #2}%
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\xchapter}{ m o }{
    \begingroup
    \ProvideDocumentCommand{\schapterheadendvskip}{}{\vskip 40\p@}
    \patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\Huge}{\LARGE}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40\p@}{\schapterheadendvskip}{}{}
    \clearpage\markboth{}{}
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \markright{#1}
}{
    \renewcommand{\schapterheadendvskip}{\vskip
        15\p@{\normalfont\Large\centering#2\par\nobreak} \vskip 20\p@}
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1:\space#2}
    \markright{#1: #2}
}
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\setlipsumdefault{1-24}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter{A chapter without a subtitle}
\lipsum
\mychapterwithsubtitle{Chapter with many many little
ducklings}{And a subtitle}
\lipsum
\mychapterwithsubtitle{no ducklings}{but some puppies}
\lipsum
\xchapter{There once was a little duckling}[and it was sooo cute]
\lipsum
\xchapter{The first law of thermodynamics}
\lipsum
\chapter*{Look at the header on the next odd page}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```